# Installing gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.0'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems

I'm using ruby and rails and am installing this gem:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.0'
```

I get this error when using `bundle install`:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) for "s3.amazonaws.com" port 443 (https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.0.4.2.gem)
An error occurred while installing bootstrap-sass (2.0.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bootstrap-sass -v '2.0.4.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your gem `source` in Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

then give `bundle install`.

in Gemfile 1st line add the line

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

Comment: how to write source in gem file ? right now i have write down this gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.0'

Comment: add it top of the `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.0'`